# Post Method in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I wrote Power query to post method like follows

```
  let
    url = "https://XXXXXXXXXX/OAuth/Token",
    body = "{
              ""grant_type"": ""password"",
              ""client_id"": ""XXXXXXXX"",
              ""client_secret"": ""XXXXXXXXX"",
              ""redirect_uri"": ""https://XXXXXXX/home/"",
              ""username"": ""user"",
              ""password"": ""password""

    }",
   Source  = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,
   [ 
     Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
     Content=Text.ToBinary(body)
   ]
   )
   ),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source)
in
   #"Converted to Table"
```

But iam getting 400 bad request error like

```
DataSource.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://XXXXX/OAuth/Token' (400): Bad Request
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Web
    DataSourcePath=https://XXXXXXX/OAuth/Token
    Url=https://XXXXXXXXXX/OAuth/Token
```

When I tried using postman I am getting 200 Ok status . Whats the main error in my PQL code?

Comment: I found the reason: my client won't accept binary format body. So suggest better code for this:  **Content=Text.ToBinary(body)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send body as urlencoded strings joint by ampersand instead of JSON

So body should look like this

```
body="grant_type=password&client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FXXXXXXX%2Fhome%2F&username=user&password=password"
```

Look at this - [Power Query, make http POST request with form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151940/power-query-make-http-post-request-with-form-data/50356349#50356349)