# POST method in Power Query 400 Bad Request

Tags: post, powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to receive data from an API, but it's POST method, so I'm trying to send the data, but it won't

```
let
    body =  [COD_INT= "886000", COD_INT_CSO= "0"],
    Parsed_JSON = Json.FromValue(body),
    Source = Web.Contents("https://apixxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy.com.br/api/CursosConcluidos", 
            [
                Headers= [#"User-Token" ="673E9CAF-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxx-xx-968"],
                Content = Parsed_JSON
            ]
        ),
    final = Json.Document(Source)
in
    final
```

In Postman it works perfectly

[Print from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkb0H.png)

I tried the same from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151940/power-query-make-http-post-request-with-form-data) but it's the same result

Changing or not the `ParsedJSON` in Binary gives the same result, 400

Comment: Send both the postman and power query requests to an HTTP Echo service and compare the requests.  eg https://learning.postman.com/docs/developer/echo-api/ or https://httpbin.org/  Or compare them in Fiddler

Comment: I'm limited to installing things and accessing websites in my office

Comment: Then use the HTTP Echo services.